# Jest: Programmatically ignore specific lines?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, relayjs, istanbul

Is there any way to ignore specific lines programmatically from Jest coverage? I know it can be done manually by adding `/* istanbul ignore next */` lines but we need a way to do this programmatically.

The use case is we have Relay.createContainer() calls on many components and they define fragments. We globally mock Relay, but the functions defined in the fragments are not covered. I tried writing a babel-plugin (to add `/* istanbul ignore next */` lines), but that doesn't work since the coverage is reported on the source-mapped code.

I also tried adding assertions in the global mock we have defined (and calling the fragment functions inside of a try/catch to artificially cover that line, and that works, but that seems super hacky and would slow down the tests). Was wondering if anyone has any thoughts on this or has done something similar?

Comment: Did you found out how to achieve this?